# Gnome 42 Wayland - VMware - A white square appears when I click on the edges of the screen

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, wayland, vmware-workstation

A white square appears when I click on the edges of the screen if I am under
`VMware Workstation 16 Pro - 16.2.3 build-19376536`.
This thing only happens when I use `Wayland`, with `Xorg` the problem does not arise.
I am using `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop` with `Gnome 42` (Default).
This problem has already been reported at the following link:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4601

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is caused by a bug in VMware in the drag and drop detection feature.
So disabling drag and drop may be one solution, if you can live with that.

Comment: This is the last resort. Apparently there are no better solutions at the moment. :-(
Hope VMware team takes care of this problem.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo VMWare is definitely aware of the issue, they have a bug filed on their Github. Doesn't look there's been much activity in the past months though. Commenting on the issue - assuming you haven't already - could bring more attention.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your cursor theme is set by other DE (e.g. KDE), so reset it to gnome ones will fix it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme Adwaita
```